# TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON when trying to POST request

Tags: angular

I am getting the error in the title and here is the full stack trace, i am not sure what it is, any insight is welcomed!

```
browser_adapter.js:84 EXCEPTION: Error in ./ParametersFormComponent class ParametersFormComponent - inline template:3:31BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.js:84BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup @ browser_adapter.js:94ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.js:65next @ application_ref.js:348schedulerFn @ async.js:89SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:225SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:174Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:124Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:88Subject._finalNext @ Subject.js:128Subject._next @ Subject.js:120Subject.next @ Subject.js:77EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:77onError @ ng_zone.js:124onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.js:74ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:327Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:233NgZoneImpl.runInnerGuarded @ ng_zone_impl.js:86NgZone.runGuarded @ ng_zone.js:240outsideHandler @ dom_events.js:27ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:423
browser_adapter.js:84 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSONBrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.js:84ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.js:74next @ application_ref.js:348schedulerFn @ async.js:89SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:225SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:174Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:124Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:88Subject._finalNext @ Subject.js:128Subject._next @ Subject.js:120Subject.next @ Subject.js:77EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:77onError @ ng_zone.js:124onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.js:74ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:327Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:233NgZoneImpl.runInnerGuarded @ ng_zone_impl.js:86NgZone.runGuarded @ ng_zone.js:240outsideHandler @ dom_events.js:27ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:423
browser_adapter.js:84 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.js:84ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.js:77next @ application_ref.js:348schedulerFn @ async.js:89SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:225SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:174Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:124Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:88Subject._finalNext @ Subject.js:128Subject._next @ Subject.js:120Subject.next @ Subject.js:77EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:77onError @ ng_zone.js:124onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.js:74ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:327Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:233NgZoneImpl.runInnerGuarded @ ng_zone_impl.js:86NgZone.runGuarded @ ng_zone.js:240outsideHandler @ dom_events.js:27ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:423
browser_adapter.js:84 TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at Object.stringify (native)
    at ParametersFormComponent.onSubmit (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:61451:25)
    at DebugAppView._View_ParametersFormComponent0._handle_ngSubmit_7_0 (ParametersFormComponent.ngfactory.js:1809:28)
    at http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:57019:24
    at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:11839:54)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:48280:16)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:48229:22)
    at Subscriber._next (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:48179:26)
    at Subscriber.next (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:48143:18)
    at EventEmitter.Subject._finalNext (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:9733:30)
    at EventEmitter.Subject._next (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:9725:18)
    at EventEmitter.Subject.next (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:9682:14)BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.js:84ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.js:78next @ application_ref.js:348schedulerFn @ async.js:89SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:225SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:174Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:124Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:88Subject._finalNext @ Subject.js:128Subject._next @ Subject.js:120Subject.next @ Subject.js:77EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:77onError @ ng_zone.js:124onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.js:74ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:327Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:233NgZoneImpl.runInnerGuarded @ ng_zone_impl.js:86NgZone.runGuarded @ ng_zone.js:240outsideHandler @ dom_events.js:27ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:423
browser_adapter.js:84 ERROR CONTEXT:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.js:84ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.js:81next @ application_ref.js:348schedulerFn @ async.js:89SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:225SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:174Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:124Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:88Subject._finalNext @ Subject.js:128Subject._next @ Subject.js:120Subject.next @ Subject.js:77EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:77onError @ ng_zone.js:124onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.js:74ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:327Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:233NgZoneImpl.runInnerGuarded @ ng_zone_impl.js:86NgZone.runGuarded @ ng_zone.js:240outsideHandler @ dom_events.js:27ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:423
browser_adapter.js:84 DebugContext {_view: _View_ParametersFormComponent0, _nodeIndex: 7, _tplRow: 3, _tplCol: 31}BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.js:84ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.js:82next @ application_ref.js:348schedulerFn @ async.js:89SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:225SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:174Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:124Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:88Subject._finalNext @ Subject.js:128Subject._next @ Subject.js:120Subject.next @ Subject.js:77EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:77onError @ ng_zone.js:124onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.js:74ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:327Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:233NgZoneImpl.runInnerGuarded @ ng_zone_impl.js:86NgZone.runGuarded @ ng_zone.js:240outsideHandler @ dom_events.js:27ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:423
:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3327 Uncaught EXCEPTION: Error in ./ParametersFormComponent class ParametersFormComponent - inline template:3:31
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at Object.stringify (native)
    at ParametersFormComponent.onSubmit (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:61451:25)
    at DebugAppView._View_ParametersFormComponent0._handle_ngSubmit_7_0 (ParametersFormComponent.ngfactory.js:1809:28)
    at http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:57019:24
    at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:11839:54)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:48280:16)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:48229:22)
    at Subscriber._next (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:48179:26)
    at Subscriber.next (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:48143:18)
    at EventEmitter.Subject._finalNext (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:9733:30)
    at EventEmitter.Subject._next (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:9725:18)
    at EventEmitter.Subject.next (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:9682:14)
ERROR CONTEXT:
[object Object]
Navigated to http://localhost:4200/?
```

component

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES, Validators, AbstractControl, Control } from '@angular/forms';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'parameters-form',
    directives: [REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES],
    templateUrl: 'form.template.html'
})
export class ParametersFormComponent {
  response: {};

  myForm: FormGroup;

  systemParameters: AbstractControl;
  param: AbstractControl;
  liftOperator: AbstractControl;
  restrictOperator: AbstractControl;
  xInitial: AbstractControl;

  system_arr: number[];
  param_arr: number[];
  restrict_arr: number[];
  lift_arr: number[];
  xinitial_arr: number[];

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.myForm = new FormGroup({
      'realisations' : new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'numConstSteps' : new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'timeHorizon': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'continuationStep' : new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'continuationStepSign' : new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'numberOfModelParameters' : new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'systemParameters' : new FormControl(''),
      'param' : new FormControl(''),
      'netLogoFile' : new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'numberOfModelVariables' : new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'restrictOperator' : new FormControl(''),
      'liftOperator' : new FormControl(''),
      'xInitial' : new FormControl('')
    });

    this.system_arr = [];
    this.param_arr = [];
    this.restrict_arr = [];
    this.lift_arr = [];
    this.xinitial_arr = [];
    this.param = this.myForm.controls["param"];
    this.systemParameters = this.myForm.controls['systemParameters'];
    this.restrictOperator = this.myForm.controls['restrictOperator'];
    this.liftOperator = this.myForm.controls['liftOperator'];
    this.xInitial = this.myForm.controls['xInitial'];
  }

  addToArray(event, value: number, target: string): void {
    if (event.which === 13) {

      switch (target) {
        case 'systemParameters':
          this.system_arr.push(value);
          (<Control>this.systemParameters).updateValue('');
          break;
        case 'param':
          this.param_arr.push(value);
          (<Control>this.param).updateValue('');
          break;
        case 'liftOperator':
          this.lift_arr.push(value);
          (<Control>this.liftOperator).updateValue('');
          break;
        case 'restrictOperator':
          this.restrict_arr.push(value);
          (<Control>this.restrictOperator).updateValue('');
          break;
        case 'xInitial':
          this.xinitial_arr.push(value);
          (<Control>this.xInitial).updateValue('');
          break;

      }
    }
  }

  deleteItem(value: any, target: string): void {
    let pos = 0;
    switch (target) {
      case 'systemParameters':
        pos = this.system_arr.indexOf(value);
        this.system_arr.splice(pos, 1);
        break;
      case 'param':
        pos = this.param_arr.indexOf(value);
        this.param_arr.splice(pos, 1);
        break;
      case 'liftOperator':
        pos = this.lift_arr.indexOf(value);
        this.lift_arr.splice(pos, 1);
        break;
      case 'restrictOperator':
        pos = this.restrict_arr.indexOf(value);
        this.restrict_arr.splice(pos, 1);
        break;
      case 'xInitial':
        pos = this.xinitial_arr.indexOf(value);
        this.xinitial_arr.splice(pos, 1);
        break;

    }
  }

  isFullfilled(m: number, n: number) {

    if (
          m == this.restrict_arr.length
          && m == this.xinitial_arr.length
          && m == this.lift_arr.length
          && n == this.param_arr.length
          && n == this.system_arr.length
       ) {
         if (m != 0 && n != 0 ){
           return true;
         }

       }

       return null;
  }
  onSubmit() {

    this.myForm.value.systemParameters = this.system_arr;
    this.myForm.value.liftOperator = this.lift_arr;
    this.myForm.value.restrictOperator = this.restrict_arr;
    this.myForm.value.param = this.param_arr;
    this.myForm.value.xInitial = this.xinitial_arr;

    let Form = JSON.stringify(this.myForm);

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/webhook', Form, { headers: headers })
    .map((data: Response) => data.json())
    .subscribe(
      data => this.response = data,
      error => console.log(error)
    );

    console.log('your submitted value:', this.myForm.value);
  }

}
```

Was working fine before i ported it from Beta to RC5

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The error seems to be due to the fact that i was trying to stringify the entire myForm object where as what i wanted was to stringify only the values

the correct syntax

```
let Form = JSON.stringify(this.myForm.value);
```

Comment: sir in my case i have an object inside another object can you tell me how to fix in case of nested  object?

Answer (score 14):

That's probably because of circular dependency in the object. In that case, it's not possible to stringify but it's always possible to log to browser console. So we can create a very basic pipe for this purpose.

in `app.module.ts`:

```js
import { LogPipe } from './log.pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    //...
    LogPipe,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

log.pipe.ts:

```js
@Pipe({name: 'log'})
export class LogPipe implements PipeTransform {
    public transform(value: object): void {
        console.log(value);
        return;
    }
}
```

Then we can use the pipe for fast logging

```html
{{'some text' | log}}
```

Comment: I don't see any './log/pipe' in my project. Where can I find this? I am using Angular 13

Comment: @RaphaelPinel you need to create it it's the second script

Answer (score 4):

In Addition to already provided answers, here is what you can do when you intend to post the entire form values.

**Form example:**

```
<form #formData="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(formData)">
    <input ngModel="my value" name="email" id="email" ...>
    ...
</form>
```

**In ts:**

```
submit(formData: any) {
    const data = JSON.stringify(formData.value);
    this.myService.postData(data)...
}
```

You are getting the values of the entire form from `formData.value` then stringify using `JSON.stringify(obj)`

I hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 3):

This code will fail for circular reference:

```
JSON.stringify(circularReference);
```

// TypeError: cyclic object value

Use the below code:

```
    const getCircularReplacer = () => {
  const seen = new WeakSet();
  return (key, value) => {
    if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null) {
      if (seen.has(value)) {
        return;
      }
      seen.add(value);
    }
    return value;
  };
};

JSON.stringify(circularReference, getCircularReplacer());
```

Answer (score 3):

The error seems to be due to the fact that I was trying to `stringify` the entire `myForm` object whereas what I wanted was to `stringify` only the values.

The correct syntax:

```js
let Form = JSON.stringify(this.myForm.value);
```

You can also try `toString()`.

Answer (score 2):

use form.value as the following code:

```js
      onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
        this.userService.login(form.value).subscribe(
          (res: any) => {
            localStorage.setItem('token', res.token);
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
          },
          error => {
            if (error.status == 400)
              this.tostarService.error('Invalid Username or password!', 'Authentication Failed');
            else
              console.log(error);

          }
        );
      }
```

Comment: When possible, please make an effort to provide additional explanation instead of just code. Such answers tend to be more useful as they help members of the community and especially new developers better understand the reasoning of the solution, and can help prevent the need to address follow-up questions.

Answer (score 2):

One of the way is you can make use of angular's built-in 'json' pipe also.
For that, you need to add angular pipe in your component the this.myForm needs to pass in the pipe method.
In the template, you can simply use `{{ myForm.value | json }}`.