# Error! TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mongoose

Error

```
Error! TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'FormGroup'
    |     property 'controls' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'userName' -> object with constructor 'FormControl'
    --- property '_parent' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at HttpRequest.serializeBody (http.js:1008)
    at Observable._subscribe (http.js:2408)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
    at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:28)
    at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:9)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (mergeMap.js:59)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:53)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js:36)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
```

I'm getting above error while sending registration form data to backend. I'm new to Node.js and Express server I didn't understand what exactly the error is. Below are the code snippets. I used angular as a frontend and Mongoose as database.

User.js

```
const express=require("express");

const User=require("../DB/User");
const router=express.Router();

router.get("/", (req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
})

router.post("/", async (req,res)=>{
    let usermodel= new User({
        userName:req.body.userName,
        password:req.body.password,
        email:req.body.email,
        address:req.body.address
    });
   await usermodel.save();
    res.json(usermodel);
})

module.exports=router;
```

server.js

```
const express=require("express");
const app=express();
const bodyparser=require("body-parser");
const port=4400;
const connectDB=require("./DB/connection");
const userapi=require("./api/User");
const cors=require('cors');

app.use('/users',userapi);
app.use(cors);
connectDB();
app.use(bodyparser.json())
app.use(express.json({extended:false}))






app.listen(port,()=>{console.log("Server is running on" +" "+ port)})
```

Schema

```
const mongoose=require("mongoose");

const user = new mongoose.Schema({
    userName:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    address:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    }
});

module.exports=User=mongoose.model("user",user);
```

Comment: You get this error in the UI or the backend?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON when trying to POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906080/typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json-when-trying-to-post-request)

Comment: Hi maazadeeb i'm getting that error from backend

Comment: Thankyou maazadeeb it is working fine now there is an issue with front end code only.